# Getting a list of nodes of a specific type (eg, forum) via REST API

Tags: 7, services

I am using Drupal 7, with the Services module. I have the REST API enabled.

I have successfully done a user.login, and have retrieved the session id and session name, and then constructed the Cookie from same.  I can successfully get a list of ALL nodes using this:

```
curl -i -X GET \
  -H Cookie:SESS02cbaaadbeeef=Dw8dsijhd9usdkjlb4Plsz_dipuJumGww \
  -H Accept:application/json \
  http://myserver/rest/node
```

How do I get the list of nodes of a specific type? Eg, nodes of type=forum ?

I tried

```
curl -i -X GET \
  -H Cookie:SESS02cbaaadbeeef=Dw8dsijhd9usdkjlb4Plsz_dipuJumGww \
  -H Accept:application/json \
  http://myserver/rest/node?type=forum
```

But that gave me the same list of all nodes.

---

**Edit**.  this is what worked for me:

```
curl -i -X GET \
  -H Cookie:SESS02cbaaadbeeef=Dw8dsijhd9usdkjlb4Plsz_dipuJumGww \
  -H Accept:application/json \
  'http://myserver/rest/node?parameters\[type\]=forum'
```

Thanks to [burnsjeremy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/151561/26722).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Services 3.x**

You would use the parameters like this:
http://localhost/endpoint/node?parameters[type]=node_type

You can find out more how to use this by looking in the code (going off memory here):
File: services/resources/node_resource.inc
function: _node_resource_index

Comment: THANK YOU! Worked perfectly. There is a need for more examples in the docs. I will read the code you suggested.