# How do I create a Forum topic post?

Tags: 7, services

I'd like to be able to create a topic on an existing forum, using the REST API exposed by the Services module. This is drupal7 and services 3.x .

via the REST interface, I can successfully:

- query the index of forums  `GET /rest/node?parameters\[type\]=forum`
- retrieve a single forum post.  `GET /rest/node/8`
- update forum posts (via PUT)  `PUT /rest/node/8   ...`

I have not been able to create a forum post. 
I tried many different variations of the JSON payload, and have not yet found the secret to success.

Example:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  -H Cookie:SESSe6a353351df0bfa8deadcafe=B0ZkiW3-U2x93yJU-deadbeef \
  -H X-CSRF-Token:PSCd5qIdddax0Mh5gfnOM872hdj893-eeeeffff \
  -H Accept:application/json \
  -H content-type:application/json \
  http://myserver/rest/node \
  -d '{
    "title": "This is a test post", 
    "body": {
      "und": [{
        "value" : "This is a test post. Please ignore.",
        "summary": "test1",
        "format": "filtered_html"
      }]
    },
    "type": "forum", 
    "language": "und",
    "status": "1",
    "forum_tid": "8"
  }'
```

The error looks like this

```
{
  "form_errors": {
    "taxonomy_forums][und":"An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."
  }
}
```

I have tried many variations of the payload, and always get the same error. I think the error means I need to pass different data. But I don't know which different data. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er, yes, I just succeeded in *creating a Forum topic*, after many trials. This was successful :

```
curl -i -X POST \
  -H Cookie:SESSe6a353351df0bfa8deadcafe=B0ZkiW3-U2x93yJU-deadbeef \
  -H X-CSRF-Token:PSCd5qIdddax0Mh5gfnOM872hdj893-eeeeffff \
  -H Accept:application/json \
  -H content-type:application/json \
  http://myserver/rest/node \
  -d '{
    "type": "forum", 
    "title": "test post?", 
    "language": "und",
    "taxonomy_forums": {
      "und": "1"
    },
    "body": {
      "und": [{
        "value" : "test post",
        "summary": "this is a test1",
        "format": "full_html"
      }]
    }
  }'
```

The key difference was, I think, adding this to the JSON:

```
    "taxonomy_forums": {
      "und": "1"
    },
```

I guessed this, based on a view of the Firefox firebug Net panel, when using the UI to post a new forum topic. This number specifies the forum to which the new topic should be associated. It is a different matter to [get the list of forum topics](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/151550/26722)!

Maybe this will help others.

Comment: The drupal services module needs "smartdocs".