# Retrieve the list of posts for a particular forum

Tags: 7, services

From [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/151550/26722), I know how to retrieve a list of forum posts (forum topics?) from drupal.

```
curl -i -X GET  \
 -H Cookie:SESSe6a353351df0bcafe98787beef=B0YAHD3-reWwwW-kzhqw6A-SgeShSYUAAQQjh \
 'http://myserver/rest/node?parameters\[type\]=forum'
```

Now, I'd like to limit the list of forum posts to those belonging to a particular forum.  How do I filter the result by forum? I know the forum tid. I just don't know how to format the query.

This doesn't cut it:

```
curl -i -X GET  \
 -H Cookie:SESSe6a353351df0bcafe98787beef=B0YAHD3-reWwwW-kzhqw6A-SgeShSYUAAQQjh \
 'http://myserver/rest/node?parameters\[type\]=forum&tid=4'
```

The above returns all forum posts. This also does not work:

```
curl -i -X GET  \
 -H Cookie:SESSe6a353351df0bcafe98787beef=B0YAHD3-reWwwW-kzhqw6A-SgeShSYUAAQQjh \
 'http://myserver/rest/node?parameters\[type\]=forum&parameters\[tid\]=4'
```

It gives me:

> "Invalid query provided, double check that the fields and parameters you defined are correct and exist. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tid' in 'where clause'"

I get the same error if I try to reference `parameters\[taxonomy_forums\]`

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all posts (forum topics) for a particular forum with id=4:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  -H Cookie:SESSe6a3baadbeef=ovQpO6aYeehaw_3W4onya22i9bonusQW \
  -H X-CSRF-Token:v6j7r9RactujA872hSHSKW-mYYWAA \
  -H Accept:application/json \
  -H Content-Type:application/json \
  http://myserver/rest/taxonomy_term/selectNodes \
  -d '{"tid":4}'
```

To find the mapping between forums and tids, refer to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/151786/26722).

I don't know how to do a parameterized query (GET) to retrieve forum topics. As far as I can tell you need to use POST, as described here.